# asking numbers in html, adding in js, printing in html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, frontend

here you can see my code im stuck with
trying to input 2 numbers by user in html
calling function then adding those 2 in js
then printing in html

html.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> JavaScript | Basics</title>
    <script src="basics.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- <input type="number" name="a" value="0" id="a">
  <input type="number" name="b" value="0" id="b">
  <button type="button" onsubmit="window.alert(a+b)" name="button">j</button>
  < Start JavaScript Here -->
  <form  onsubmit='sum(a,b)'>
  <label for="a">Input number a</label>
  <input type="number" name="a" value="0" id='a'>
  <br>
  <label for="a">Input number b</label>
  <input type="number" name="b" value="0" id='b'>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  <output id="total"></output>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

js

```
// 34343
// window.alert()
function sum(a, b) {
  console.log('hello world');

  var c;
  c.value = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
  console.log(c.value);
  window.alert(c.value);
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'The value of  s ' + c.value;
}

// </script>
```

help please

Comment: When you call sum(a,b) on form submit, you haven't defined variables a and b. What does your console say?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to sum the two values there is no need to use Form tag.

The Form tag is usually used to send data to a server for processing.

You can read more about Form tag here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Using plain JS your code would be something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JavaScript | Basics</title>
    <script src="basics.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div> <!-- Remove Form-->
      <label for="a">Input number a</label>
      <input type="number" name="a" value="0" id="a" />
      <br />
      <label for="a">Input number b</label>
      <input type="number" name="b" value="0" id="b" />
      <button onclick="sum()" name="submit">Submit</button>   <!-- on click calls sum function-->
      <output id="total"></output>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function sum() {
      let a = document.getElementById('a').value; // get value from 'a' input
      let b = document.getElementById('b').value; // get value from 'b' input
      console.log('hello world');

      let c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b); // sum value into 'c' variable

      document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'The value of  s ' + c; // adding innerHtml with value of 'c'
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks,but how can i do using external js file

Comment: why even wrong value was not printing, 
"" The Sum is "" statement was also not printed for what reason, and why it was flashing on submit button instead of printing..

Comment: can we use var instead of let

Comment: can;t we pass parameters in functions

Comment: you can add I external JS file using script tag like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-javascript-file.js"></script>

Comment: It was "flashing" because the form was submitting and when it happens the page is reloaded passing the form values as querystring

Comment: Yes, you can use either var or let in this case. You can read more about the differences between var and let here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Comment: Yes, you can pass parameters to function, however in this case you did not have the input values, you have to capture the values of the inputs inside the function